# WP hook function 'save_post'

Tags: php, wordpress

Was trying to use the save_post hook to create a html file, every time a file is saved.

But after editing the content and on trying to update an existing post, wp returns the message

> "Not Found Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found.
>   Perhaps searching will help."

The post is neither updated in WP, nor the function 'write_single_post' creates a html file as intended. Is there anything wrong with the way the function and the hook is used.....

```
function write_single_post($post_ID)  
{
global $folder;

 $file = $folder.$post_ID.".html";

$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$string ="data goes here\n";
echo (fwrite($fh,$string))?"written":"not writtern";
fclose($fh);
}

do_action('save_post','write_single_post',$post_ID);
```

Answer (score 4):

`do_action()` creates a new hook. `add_action()` uses an existing hook. For example,

```
function write_single_post($post_ID)  
{
 global $folder;

 $file = $folder.$post_ID.".html";

 $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
 $string ="data goes here\n";
 echo (fwrite($fh,$string))?"written":"not writtern";
 fclose($fh);
}

add_action('save_post','write_single_post');
```

it only needs the hook & your function in this case. The post ID is passed in automatically.