# How to make a wordpress plugin interact with posts & pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I started to really sit down and learn PHP about a week ago, so I'm a tad new at this. Anyways I'm trying to figure out how I can make my WordPress plugin interact with posts & pages.

Essentially I am defining a keyword & then making that keyword a hyperlink. I know there are other plugins out there that already do this, but I'm not sure how they actually get the content from the PHP file to edit the posts & pages.

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting the keyword to be a link everywhere on the page or just in the post/page itself? For example if the keyword is music, and music is in your your footer as well as the article, do you want it to become a link in both places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify what [WP hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) you need, depending on what you want to do and when you want to do it. Then attach a function that does what you need.

Comment: Hey @Jage,

I'm going through the different hooks now, essentially I just want to have my keyword pulled from a database & then scan the post/page for that keyword. 

If it's found, it converts that keyword into a hyperlink with a link it pulls from the database as well.

At first I thought it would be something like publish_page, but a lot of the documentation for WordPress hooks doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: I would use save_post if I were you. Here is an example of someone who uses that hook to save data to static file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055070/wp-hook-function-save-post